# Client-side validation does not work when inherting from RequiredAttribute in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I created an inherited attribute like this in ASP.NET MVC3:

```
public sealed class RequiredFromResourceAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public RequiredFromResourceAttribute(string errorResourceName, string errorResourceTypeName)
    {
        this.ErrorMessageResourceName = errorResourceName;
        this.ErrorMessageResourceType = Type.GetType(errorResourceTypeName);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
[RequiredFromResource("Title", "Resources.Resource, MyProject.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

It didn't work and the MVC ignored it. Then I create a simpler class which just inherited from RequiredAttribute like this:

```
public class MyRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
}
```

I use it like that I said. But it didn't work again.

**Although, all these ways work on "DisplayNameAtrribute" perfectly.**

What is the problem?

Comment: In my opinion, marcind's answer handles this better than SkipHarris'. The RequiredAttributeAdapter in Skip's seems to cause the client side validation to use the regular Required attribute instead of the RequiredFromResourceAttribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by adding the following code in Global.asax: (found the answer [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1528277.aspx/1))

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredLocalizableAttribute), typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
```

Alternatively, using marcind's solution, I found that the constructor for `ModelClientValidationRequiredRule` requires an error message. Here is an updated version that includes the display name for the field:

```
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        string msg = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRequiredRule(msg);
    }
```

Comment: @marcind's answer seems to handle this much better. Using the RequiredAttributeAdapter seems to call the regular Required attribute instead of the custom one.

Answer (score 3):

It's only client-side validation that does not work with inherited attributes. The reason for that is that MVC uses strict type equality when mapping server-side attributes to client validation behaviors.

To work around this you will need your custom attribute to implement `IClientValidatable`:

```
public class MyRequiredAttribute : IClientValidatable {
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) {
         yield return new ModelClientValidationRequiredRule();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a much better way to handle this than @SkipHarris'. Using the RequiredAttributeAdapter seems to call the regular Required attribute instead of the custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the above, the complete attribute for LocalizedRequiredAttribute using a default resource string of Resource.ValueRequired which is defined in my resources as
"The {0} field is required."

```
public class LocalizedRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute, IClientValidatable 
{
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var msg = new ResourceManager(ErrorMessageResourceType).GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName);
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRequiredRule(string.Format(msg, metadata.DisplayName));
    }

    public LocalizedRequiredAttribute(string errorResourceName = null, string errorResourceTypeName = null)
    {
        this.ErrorMessageResourceName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorResourceName) ? nameof(Resource.ValueRequired) : errorResourceName;
        this.ErrorMessageResourceType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorResourceTypeName) ? typeof(Resource) : Type.GetType(errorResourceTypeName);
    }
}
```