# Compare attribute does not use Display attribute of compared property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, properties, attributes, data-annotations

I have a ViewModel used for changing a password, and it uses the `Compare` DataAnnotation like so:

```
[Display(Name = "New Password")]
public string New { get; set; }

[Compare("New")]
[Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Unfortunately the `Compare` attribute does not utilize the `Display` attribute of the compared property.

The error message displays as

```
'Confirm Password' and 'New' do not match.
```

which you can see uses the comparing property's `Display` attribute, but not the compared property's.

I'll also specify that I don't want to use the `ErrorMessage` parameter because then I'd be hard-coding the property name rather than simply acquiring it from an existing attribute. I'd like to keep this solution as best-practice as possible.

How can I make the `Compare` attribute utiliize the `Display` attribute of the compared property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this may be some issue with the Compare attribute, since you can see an OtherDisplayName attribute in its list of properties, and it correctly uses the Display Name for the property it is decorating ("Confirm Password" and not "ConfirmPassword").

One work around I have found is to simply create a new class that inherits from CompareAttribute, like so:

```
public class CompareWithDisplayName : CompareAttribute
{
    public CompareWithDisplayName(string otherProperty) : base(otherProperty)
    {
    }
}
```

Then use it on your property:

```
[Display(Name = "New Password")]
public string New { get; set; }


[Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
[CompareWithDisplayName("New")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

I honestly have no idea why this works. It could be that it is something to do with reflection or the order in which it works out what each property's display attribute is. By creating a custom version of it, perhaps the ordering is changed? Either way, this did the trick for me :)

**Edit 2**
Sorry, forgot to add the extra part needed for client side validation, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749657/client-side-validation-does-not-work-when-inherting-from-requiredattribute-in-as). You can either add this in your *Global.asax.cs* file:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(CompareWithDisplayName), typeof(CompareAttributeAdapter))
```

or implement the IClientValidatable interface on the custom attribute. Both of these are shown in the link

Comment: Sorry about that, Ive updated the answer with the additional work youll need to do for that :)

Comment: CompareAttributeAdapter class seems to be internal to the System.Web.Mvc assembly, how have you been able to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late, but I had the same issue in Asp.Net Core Razor Page Web App, and the easy fix was to make a new InputModel class with the Password and ConfirmPassword properties.Then, bind the form inputs to the InputModel properties.

Like this:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel UserPassword { get; set; }

    public class InputModel {
      [BindProperty]
      [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "La contraseña es obligatoria.")]
      [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-ZñÑ0-9]+$",ErrorMessage = "Sólo se permiten letras y números.")]
      [StringLength(12,ErrorMessage = "La contraseña no debe tener más de 12 caracteres.")]
      [MaxLength(12,ErrorMessage = "La contraseña no debe tener más de 12 caracteres.")]
      [MinLength(2,ErrorMessage = "La contraseña no debe tener menos de 2 caracteres.")]
      public string Password { get; set; }

      [BindProperty]
      [Display(Name = "Confirmación de Contraseña")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "La contraseña es obligatoria.")]
      [Compare(nameof(Password),ErrorMessage = "La contraseña de confirmación no coincide.")]
      public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It is never too late to shed some light on old questions even if the author of the question already accepted one of the answers. It may help other stackoverflow users.